# Variable undefined after assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

Why is `resultofgetCauses` undefined? I'm not sure if the function is not returning `currentCauses` or if it not being assigned to `resultofgetCauses` . . . or if this has something to do with asynchronicity.

```
function getCauses(){

  var currentCauses;
  client = pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done){

    if(err) console.log(err);

    client.query('SELECT * FROM causes', function(err, result){
      //console.log(result.rows);
      console.log('poo');
      currentCauses=result.rows;
      //console.log(currentCauses);
    });

  });

  return currentCauses;
};

var resultofgetCauses = getCauses();
```

Comment: Asynchronous code? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: I don't think it's the asynchronicity that's the problem though

Comment: It is, `currentCauses` is `undefined` as `resultofgetCauses` gets assigned **before** `pg.connect` has time to finish. That question has an in-depth solution to your problem.

Comment: There are actually 2(nested) async calls here. `pg.connect` and `client.query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes since it's running `asynchronously`, by the time `result.rows` is assigned to the `currentCauses` variable, the line `'return currentCauses'` has already been executed thus the value is undefined.

You may want to do that as follow

```
var resulttofgetCauses;
function getCauses(){
    var currentCauses;
    client = pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        client.query('SELECT * FROM causes', function(err, result){
            //console.log(result.rows);
            console.log('poo');
            currentCauses=result.rows;
            //console.log(currentCauses);
            resulttofgetCauses = currentCauses;
        });
    });
};
getCauses();
```

To be more specific with the answer, executing `'SELECT * FROM causes'` sql does not give you the result right after its execution time. It takes at least 0.00something seconds to retrieve the data from database. So in the very short time between 'executing sql' and 'receiving requested data' JavaScript has already executed `return currentCauses;` while the correct data is still in the progress of retrieving. Because it's async and won't wait. There are good example code out there on the internet you may want to check out.

Plus It's a good practice to define function as follow

```
getCauses = function () { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `currentCauses` is initialized in an async invoked function (the function passed as param to `pg.connect`) after you have already returned from `getCauses` function. By the time you return the value of `currentCauses` is undefined.